# Target word for "para que"

Tags: gramática

I was listening to news in slow Spanish today and came across the following sentence:

> **Obama dijo que le había dado más de un año al Congreso para que
>   actuara y nada había ocurrido**.

While I understand what the sentence means in essence, I am confused about the part after **para que**. Shouldn't it take an infinitive (**actuar**) since **para que** translates as "in order to" in this context? In fact, I don't even know what actuara means exactly since I couldn't find it in any dictionary. I am only guessing it to have something to do with **actuar**.

Also, does the **le** before **había** serve any particular purpose here? Would the sentence be incorrect without it since both the objects are already given explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of questions here.

First with *para que*.  Once you hit the *que*, you have initiated a new clause and need a freshly conjugated verb.  If you take out the que, then by virtue of having a verb after a preposition, an infinitive is the only option:

- Estudiaba para sacar notas buenas.
- Estudiaba para *que me diese* mi profesor buenas notas.

You can eschew the clausal form if the subject of the verb (that comes after the preposition, *sacar* in the previous example) is the same as the subject of the main clause:

- Estudiaba<sub>*(yo)*</sub> para sacar<sub>*(yo)*</sub> buenas notas.
- Estudiaba<sub>*(yo)*</sub> para que me diese<sub>*(él)*</sub> mi profesor buenas notas.

In your sentence, you can see there is a difference of subject, which normally causes the clausal form:

- Obama dijo que le había<sub>*(Obama)*</sub> dado más de un año al Congreso para que actuara<sub>*(el Congreso)*</sub>.

The *le* is completely optional since the indirect object is explicitly stated (it's only obligatory if an explicitly stated indirect object is a personal pronoun like *a mí*).

The pluperfect *había dado* and *había ocurrido* is necessary because the year he gave happened prior to when he made the statement.  After *dijo que*, the only verb forms generally allowed are pluperfect or antepreterite (happened before he said something), imperfect (happened simultaneously with when he said something), imperfect *ir a* or conditional (happened after he said something or is to happen).  In more colloquial Spanish, present tense or even future is allowable if it is current with the moment in which the reporting of what he said happens (confused yet?).

Comment: "Estudio para que **me de** el profe buenas notas" o "Estudié/estudiaba para que **me diese** el profe buenas notas", no? En eso ejemplos tiene que concordar el verbo, no?

Comment: @Diego : sí, es lo que me pasa cuando voy casi tres días sin dormir :)

Comment: @Diego **me dé**

Comment: @David, gracias, tienes toda la razón del mundo: dé (con tilde diacrítica) → del verbo dar; de (sin tilde diacrítica) → preposición. Qué pena que no pueda editar el comentario para corregirlo :(